# Any alternate method to access $_POST variables

Tags: php, post

To access data from `$_POST` method normally we use `$_POST['id']` . Is there any other method to access that variables like `$_POST[0]`, `$_POST[1]`.

Comment: You can do a `foreach` loop over `$_POST` if you don't know what keys it contains. Why do you need another way?

Comment: I don‘t really understand what is being asked here.

Comment: What is wrong with $_POST?

Comment: thank you for teaching us OP

Comment: you could access the values, with array_values($_POST); ie no associative index

Comment: $_POST['field_name'] is normal way to get POST data. Its same to ask : "Can I make a form without using Form tags.."

Comment: I just asked to simplify the code if there is more number of POST methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw post body with reading from `php://input`:

```
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Please refer to this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php) on the php website. Also note that you can fetch the output only once as `php://input` is not seekable. So you will have to store the results in a variable for further processing.

Further note that this is the **raw** post body that has to be parsed by yourself. Assuming that you have two variables `foo`, `hello` the body (`$raw_post`) will look like this:

```
var_dump($raw_post); // output: 'string(19) "foo=bar&hello=world"'
```

Comment: Why those downvotes? @hek2mgl: You should mention that one has to parse the raw input, which might not be a trivial task when dealing with all possible content types.

Comment: Ok, this should being mentioned. Have added this to the post

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$_POST[" . $key . "] = " . $value;
}
```

That will display something like:

```
$_POST[id1] = Whatever
```